# Converting string elements in a list into separate variables

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of string elements and what I want to do is to turn each element into a variable whose name is the string.

```
brands = ['Sony','Samsung','Apple','Panasonic','Sennheiser','LG','AudioTechnica','Acer','Verizon']
```

I want to create new variables Sony, Samsung, Apple, etc. which will be empty lists []. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Actually, you're probably better off leaving the list as-is.  Include the rest of your code for optimal feedback.

Comment: Don't. Use a dict. `brands = {b: [] for b in brands}`.

Comment: What about doing this bad idea? `for n in brands: locals()[n] = 'bad idea'`

Comment: @mathfux That's a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, never thought of dictionaries, that's actually the best, thank you